# Преобразование xml с помощью xlst

Tags: xml, xslt

Решаю одну задачу, полный затык. Не срабатывают даже оригинальные вещи, а-ля вырезка отдельных нодов.

```
  <!-- Выводим все, что есть в исходнике xml--> 
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>   
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Вот такая вырезка не работает-->       
  <xsl:template match="//HotelInfo" />
```

Исходный xml документ

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Task3.xsl"?>
<OTA_HotelDescriptiveInfoRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
    EchoToken="tok1" Version="2">

    <HotelDescriptiveContents>

        <HotelDescriptiveContent HotelCityCode="UK.LON"
            HotelCode="YYL" HotelCodeContext="travco" HotelName="County London (Testing)">
            <HotelInfo>
                <Descriptions>
                    <MultimediaDescriptions>
                        <MultimediaDescription>
                            <ImageItems>
                                <ImageItem>
                                    <ImageFormat>
                                        <URL>http://www.travco.co.uk/images/hotels/YYL/YYL_front.jpg
                                        </URL>
                                    </ImageFormat>
                                    <Description Caption="front" />
                                </ImageItem>
                                <ImageItem>
                                    <ImageFormat>
                                        <URL>http://www.travco.co.uk/images/hotels/YYL/YYL_bed.jpg
                                        </URL>
                                    </ImageFormat>
                                    <Description Caption="rooms" />
                                </ImageItem>
                                <ImageItem>
                                    <ImageFormat>
                                        <URL>http://www.travco.co.uk/images/hotels/YYL/YYL_map.jpg
                                        </URL>
                                    </ImageFormat>
                                    <Description Caption="map" />
                                </ImageItem>
                            </ImageItems>
                        </MultimediaDescription>
                        <MultimediaDescription>
                            <TextItems>
                                <Description>*** Please note that name changes are not
                                    permitted to any bookings made at this hotel.***

                                    The County is a small, friendly and economic hotel, popular with
                                    budget-minded travellers. It is conveniently situated in the
                                    heart of London within easy walking distance from Euston and
                                    King's Cross stations as well as Covent Garden, Oxford Street
                                    and The British Museum. The bathrooms are communal, every four
                                    ©, ¶, ∑, Œ rooms shares one bathroom.</Description>
                                <Description>ARRIVAL_POINT_NAME: no arrival
                                    pt, TUBE_STATION: Euston Tube Station (400m)</Description>
                            </TextItems>
                        </MultimediaDescription>
                    </MultimediaDescriptions>
                </Descriptions>
                <Services>
                    <Service Caption="78">
                        <DescriptiveText>Security safe (at reception)
                        </DescriptiveText>
                    </Service>
                    <Service Caption="158">
                        <DescriptiveText>Bar(s)</DescriptiveText>
                    </Service>
                    <Service Caption="24">
                        <DescriptiveText>Conference Facilities</DescriptiveText>
                    </Service>
                    <Service Caption="180">
                        <DescriptiveText>Breakfast Room</DescriptiveText>
                    </Service>
                    <Service Caption="137">
                        <DescriptiveText>Tea &amp; Coffee Equipment</DescriptiveText>
                    </Service>
                    <Service Caption="180">
                        <DescriptiveText>Television</DescriptiveText>
                    </Service>
                    <Service Caption="180">
                        <DescriptiveText>Radio</DescriptiveText>
                    </Service>
                </Services>
            </HotelInfo>
            <AffiliationInfo>
                <Awards>
                    <Award Provider="Hotel" Rating="1"/>
                </Awards>
            </AffiliationInfo>
            <ContactInfos>
                <ContactInfo>
                    <Addresses>
                        <Address>
                            <AddressLine>Upper Woburn Place</AddressLine>
                            <CityName>London</CityName>
                            <PostalCode>WC1H 0JW</PostalCode>
                        </Address>
                    </Addresses>
                    <Phones>
                        <Phone PhoneNumber="0044 (0)2073875544" PhoneTechType="1"/>
                        <Phone PhoneNumber="0044 (0)2078374653" PhoneTechType="3"/>
                    </Phones>
                    <Emails>
                        <Email>emcbride@travco.co.uk</Email>
                    </Emails>
                </ContactInfo>
            </ContactInfos>
        </HotelDescriptiveContent>
.............
    </HotelDescriptiveContents>
</OTA_HotelDescriptiveInfoRS>
```

И вот что нужно с ним сделать.

> Необходимо составить xml документ, содержащий :
>       1. Элементы с именами 'ContactInfo', 'MultimediaDescription' и 'ImageFormat' должны быть удалены, их потомки поднимаются на уровень
>   выше (т.е. просто теряют родителя).
>       2. Элементы, в имени которых встречается сочетание 'rds', также должны быть удалены, с переносом их дочерних элементов на уровень
>   выше.
>       3. Атрибут 'Caption', должен стать дочерним элементом (своего элемента).
>       4. Если элемент содержит несколько дочерних элементов 'Description', вывести следует только один, который содержит самый
>   длинный текст.
>       5. Встречающиеся в тексте символы ©, ¶, ∑, Œ  - удалить.
>       6. Элемент 'DescriptiveText' перевести в аттрибут, элемента 'Service'.
>       7. Все атрибуты и элементы, неупомянутые выше, скопировать без изменений.

**Какую механику решения я рассматриваю:**

1. Вывожу в шаблон дочерние ноды 'ContactInfo', 'MultimediaDescription' и 'ImageFormat' , затем 'ContactInfo', 'MultimediaDescription' и 'ImageFormat'  вырезаю.
2. Вырезаю по шаблону
3. Проверяю условие через choose на наличие атрибута 'Caption'. Если есть, то вставляю нод 'Caption' как дочерний.  Правда непонятно как это будет работать с выводом всего исходника (думаю будет конфликт)
4. Инициализируем param str. Поиск максимальной длины string-length('Description') и затем вывод его в древо.
5. Думаю, будет подходящий вариант с функцией translate() которая "переводит" указанные символы как "".
6. Тут пока что не придумал. Вижу в туториале, что можно создать атрибут вот так .  Но тот ли это атрибут?

==================================================================
Вот такие мысли. Помогите, пожалуйста!